# The `render` function is not replacing slot content

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am using vue 2.0.

I want to generate this template:

```
<Poptip placement="right" width="400">
    <Button type="ghost">click 激活</Button>
    <div class="api" slot="content">my content</div>
</Poptip>
```

Using the `render` function:

```
render: (h, params) => {
  return h('Poptip', {
    props: {
      placement: 'right'
    }
  }, [
    h('Button', {
      props: {
        type: 'ghost'
      }
    }, 'Edit'),
    h('div', {
      props: {
        slot: 'content'
      }
    }, 'My content')
  ])
}
```

Using the template works perfectly. But, when I use the `render` function, the slot's content is not replaced with my content.

Answer (score 2):

You are specifing a `prop` named `slot` with value `content`:

```
h('div', {
  props: {
    slot: 'content'
  }
}, 'My content')
```

To simply specify a `slot` named `content`:

```
h('div', {
  slot: 'content'
}, 'My content')
```

[See the documentation.](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html)